# What does DBMS-independence at the source code level and at the level of the executable mean?

Tags: database, jdbc

From Database Management Systems, by Raghu Ramakrishnan, ‎Johannes Gehrk

> In contrast to Embedded SQL,  **ODBC and  JDBC  allow  a  single 
>   executable  to  access  different  DBMSs  without  recompilation**. 
>   Thus,  while  Embedded  SQL  is  DBMS-independent only at the source
>   code  level,  applications  using  ODBC or  JDBC  are DBMS-independent
>   at  the  source code level  and **at the level  of the executable**.

An application which uses JDBC can access only DBMSs specified in source code. So I was wondering what  it means by

- "ODBC and  JDBC  allow  a  single  executable  to  access  different  DBMSs  without  recompilation"?
- DBMS-independent "at  the  source code level"  and "at the level  of the executable"?

Answer (score 1):

While using JDBC, you typically define the database using configuration of database url, username and password. So you really need not recompile and only switching the configuration you can connect e.g. to development and production DB.

While compiling the JDBC program the database is not accessed, it could be the database even doesn't exists at the time of the compilation.

Contrary in *embedded SQL* such as *SQLJ* (I'm not sure how much embedded SQL is relevant now; SQLJ has anyway 37 tagged questions on SO) while compiling the database is accessed to check the relevant tables etc - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31227/overview.htm#i1005826).

So switching to other DB (or even after structure changes in the same DB) the program must be recompiled.

This is my interpretation what the quote try to say. Let me conclude that under DBMS-independence is typically meant a possible switch between different DBMS (such as Oracle and MySQL), which is definitively not relevant in this context.

Comment: This comment doesn't seem to address the meat of the question. Further it is factually incorrect at many points. Recompilation of general purpose ODBC/JDBC-compliant applications is not required when changing DBMS nor changing schema within DBMS. (Purpose-built, deployment-specific applications are another question but as stated in my own answer, such apps are not truly ODBC/JDBC-compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

Both [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/odbc-overview) and [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) are DBMS-agnostic APIs. You do not need to know anything about the eventual target DBMS, when writing ODBC or JDBC applications — in fact, those target DBMS may not even exist yet!

With ODBC- or JDBC-compliant applications, changing the target DBMS is as simple as changing the ODBC DSN or JDBC URL for the connection.

Many application developers do create DBMS-specific applications using ODBC or JDBC as their data access mechanism, by ignoring the DBMS-agnostic aspects of the ODBC and JDBC APIs, and instead choosing to use DBMS-specific SQL dialects.

Because of this specificity, these applications are not actually ODBC-/JDBC-compliant, though they are often presented as such.

You said —

> An application which uses JDBC can access only DBMSs specified in source code.

This is absolutely not the case. I suggest you read further, starting with the links I included above.

Comment: Thanks. Is `getConnection(databaseUrl)` DBMS-dependent?

Comment: No. [The documentation is your friend](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).

Comment: JDBC-compliance is only for drivers, not for aplications using drivers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - That's a complete misunderstanding. If I offer a JDBC compliant tool, I am asserting that it may be used against any DBMS with a JDBC compliant driver. If my application is MySQL-specific, or Oracle-specific, or any other DBMS-specific, it is not properly called JDBC compliant, even if it uses JDBC for its connections to the DBMS against which it runs.

Comment: @TallTed Then you're technically using the wrong term (and yes, I am aware this is nitpicking). The use of the term JDBC compliant suggest that you meet the requirements of the JDBC specification, but the JDBC specification only describes the requirements to and  behavior of drivers, and provides a TCK to test for compliance. There are no described requirements for applications themselves.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Perhaps you'll grant that lacking any described requirements, there is an implication such as I describe. I assert that the implication is stronger than you feel it to be, and that it flows from ODBC (which has an explicit statement that an ODBC "[application will be independent of any DBMS from which it accesses data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft-open-database-connectivity-odbc)").

Comment: @TallTed Lets agree to disagree on this one, otherwise we'll be here all night ;)